# jQuery Tools - load external content into overlay - with custom variable - google.maps , marker.set('id')

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-tools

Using jquery 1.7.2, jquery-tools 1.2.7, and googlemaps api v3

First, here is a snippet of my code that creates a marker in googlemaps:

```
function createMarker(latlng, id) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: googleMap,
    position: latlng,
    });

marker.set('id', id);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {               
  property_id = marker.get('id');

  alert("add listener -> " + property_id);
            $("#contentWrapBeta").overlay({
                      mask: {
                        color: '#ebecff',
                            loadSpeed: 100,
                            opacity: 0.5
                            },
                          effect: 'apple',
                          left: '2%',
                          top: '5%',
                          load: false,

                  onBeforeLoad: function() {

                  alert("on before load" + property_id);
                 var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
                 wrap.load('details.php?id=' + property_id);

                        }

              });

            alert("overlay.load ->" + property_id);
  $("#contentWrapBeta").overlay().load();

});

markers.push(marker);
}
```

So, when i click the first marker, the alert "add listener" fires with the correct property_id, the "on before load" alert has the correct property id, and the "overlay.load" has the correct ID, the popup appears, all is well....

When i click on a second marker on the map, the "add listener" alert shows the correct ID (the new marker id that i set), the "overlay.load" is correct too, however,

The "on before load" alert has the previous markers property_id (!) - no matter what im try i cant seem to update it with new markers id's that i click, its "stuck" on the first markers property_id - so the wrap.load() calls with the same &id= variable.

Can anyone tell me why - its been bugging me for days now! And i cant seem to solve it.

many thanks

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your bug here http://jsfiddle.net/xLQ4F/ but it works OK for me. What are we doing differently?

Comment: thanks - i fixed the issue - seems that jquery-tools - is the issue - once the overlay was initalised, it wouldnt pull an new variables as what youve shown here ... adding my answer

Answer (score 0):

ah i got it

Thanks to shonky on #jquery on irc.freenode.org

Seems i needed to add data() to my overlay definition

i changed this:

```
    $("#contentWrapBeta").overlay({
                  mask: {
                  ....,
              onBeforeLoad: function() {
              alert("on before load" + property_id);
              var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
              wrap.load('details.php?id=' + property_id);

             }

          });
```

to

```
$("#contentWrapBeta").data('property_id', property_id).overlay({
                  mask: {
                  ....,
              onBeforeLoad: function() {
                  var propertyA_id = $('#contentWrapBeta').data('property_id');
                  alert("on before load" + propertyA_id);
                  var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
                  wrap.load('details.php?id=' + propertyA_id);

                  }

          });
```